# How to delete certain amount of bytes in file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a file.txt which contains the text `12345` (5 bytes in total).
I want to delete `3` and shift `45` one byte to the left and in total I want to have `1245` (4 bytes in total).

Here is my code:

```py
with open ('a.txt', "r+b") as fl:
    fl.seek(0)
    onetwo = fl.read(2)
    fl.seek(3)
    fourfive = fl.read(2)
    fl.seek(0)
    fl.write(onetwo+fourfive)
```

But as a result I get this:
`12455`

I tried to truncate but truncate does not help to solve the file I am working on (not this file).

Comment: Given that python2 and python3 deals with bytes differently, perhaps you can edit your question to specify which you are using and remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: "I tried to truncate but truncate does not help to solve the file I am working on" Can you please show the code with which you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a new file:

```
with open ('a.txt', 'r') as f1, open ('b.txt', 'w') as f2:
  # read and write operations...
```

Then move files to overwrite:

```
import os
os.rename('b.txt', 'a.txt')
```

Comment: You mean there is no way to do it in the same file, right?

Comment: You don't need to create a new file.

Comment: Not with one file handle. You could read the file into memory, close the file handle, open a new file handle to the same filename and write out a subset of the file data in-memory to the new file handle.

Comment: @AlexReynolds No, you don't need to do that either. You can change the size of an open file using the `truncate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `truncate` method to shrink the file after you've shifted the bytes.

```
# Create the original file
with open('foo', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'12345')

# Shift the last two bytes, then truncate.
with open('foo', 'r+b') as f:
    f.seek(3)
    d = f.read()   # d == b'45'
    f.seek(2)
    f.write(d)  # overwrites the original 3 and 4 => b'12455'
    f.truncate()  # Shrink to the current position => b'1245'
```

In practice, you probably won't be using hard-coded offsets, but this demonstrates the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the file which can't be done in the way you tried. I tried this and it worked:

```
with open ('a.txt', "r") as fl:
    fl.seek(0)
    onetwo = fl.read(2)
    fl.seek(3)
    fourfive = fl.read(2)

with open('a.txt','w') as fl:
    fl.write(onetwo+fourfive)
```